# Need help with difficult table modeling situation

Tags: database-design, many-to-many

Database newbie here with no formal training, trying to train myself.  I was looking for a more difficult case to model and came up with following.

Hypothetical ice cream shop where there are *containers* (small cone, large cone, small, medium and large cups) each with a price and a number of scoops for each.
There are *flavors* with a price per scoop, and multiple flavors can be used for containers that can have multiple scoops.
There are *toppings* where just for simplicity I am limiting to one topping per final product including none.
I cannot understand how to get from these product parts to the `Order_Details` table.  I am used to looking a single `Products` table that relates to an `Order_Details` table that relates to `Orders` Table, but I cannot comprehend how to get from the `Containers`, `Flavors` and `Toppings` tables I have designed to the `Orders_Details` table.

I am requesting some ideas on the best way to model from my product parts to the `Order_Details` table.

[image]
Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also found a way to model the flavors, containers and toppings.  I looked at if from the perspective of a recipe.  I lumped all of the ingredients into an ingredient table, linked that to a Products_Ingredients table and then linked that to the Products table.
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably need a linking table called `ContainerFlavors` (or `IceCreamCombinations` for something more sensible) for the **many-to-many** relationship between `Containers` and `Flavors`.

That linking table would have it's own unique `ID` column, and purely store `ContainerID` and `FlavorID`. The primary key on that table would be it's `ID` column and there would be a foreign key on `ContainerID` and foreign key on `FlavorID` (and basically would store every possibly combination of `Containers` and `Flavors`).

You can store this linking table's `ID` column in the your `Order_Details` table.

You can expand the linking table out to store the `ToppingID` as well (with a foreign key to `Toppings`) for every combination of `Containers`, `Flavors`, and `Toppings`.

---

So after some sitting down and modeling out your example, I realized your example is very similar to a manufacturing schema, which is why it's a litte more complex. Please see the schema I came up with below (please ignore any minor semantical differences such as casing, compared to yours). In this example schema the term "**Combination**" can be thought of as synonymous to "**FinalProduct**" (feel free to rename things on your end, as needed).

[image: Ice Cream Schema]

In this schema you have an `Order` which can contain multiple `OrderDetails`, where each `OrderDetail` has one `Combination` (final product), but the same `Combination` can be used on multiple `OrderDetails` (e.g. if two people order "a cone of chocolate ice cream with hot fudge" combination).

The `Combinations` table is a distinct list of final products. It has a one-to-many relationship with the `CombinationsBom` table. (*BOM stands for Bill of Materials in the manufacturing industry, and is a type of mapping table that contains all the components that make up a final product.* In this case all the container + flavors + topping combinations to make up the final product `Combination`.) Every row in the `CombinationsBom` table is the `Container` with it's `Flavor` or `Topping` selection. Multiple rows can exist for the same Combination (hence the one-to-many relationship). Therefor a `Combination` that is made up of a two scoop `Container` and has no `Toppings` should have two rows in the `CombinationsBom` table, one for each `Flavor`. (*Note since BOM tables contain every possible combination of the final products, they are usually large tables.*)

*This design actually allows for multiple `Toppings` in one `Combination` as well.

There are a few other ways to model this, or minor normalizations that can be added to my example schema, but I think this is a good start for what you're trying to achieve.

Using the above schema we can write an example query like such:

```
SELECT O.OrderNumber, O.OrderDate, O.CustomerId, C.CombinationName, 
    CB.BomId, CB.CombinationID, 
    CO.ContainerName, CB.ContainerID, CO.ContainerPrice, CO.NumberOfScoops,
    CB.IsTopping, CB.FlavorOrToppingID,
    CASE WHEN CB.IsTopping = 0 THEN F.FlavorName ELSE T.ToppingName END AS FlavorOrToppingName,
    CASE WHEN CB.IsTopping = 0 THEN F.PricePerScoop ELSE T.ToppingPrice END AS Price
FROM IceCream.Orders AS O
INNER JOIN IceCream.OrderDetails AS OD
    ON O.OrderNumber = OD.OrderNumber
INNER JOIN IceCream.Combinations AS C
    ON OD.CombinationID = C.CombinationID
INNER JOIN IceCream.CombinationsBom AS CB
    ON C.CombinationID = CB.CombinationID
INNER JOIN IceCream.Containers AS CO
    ON CB.ContainerID = CO.ContainerID
LEFT JOIN IceCream.Flavors AS F
    ON CB.FlavorOrToppingID = F.FlavorID
    AND CB.IsTopping = 0
LEFT JOIN IceCream.Toppings AS T
    ON CB.FlavorOrToppingID = T.ToppingID
    AND CB.IsTopping = 1
```

To produce these kind of results:

[image: Example Output]

(Note I'm finding minor things that need to be improved in the schema design, and I'll continue to update my answer accordingly, but this should hopefully give you an idea of what's involved for modeling this kind of schema.)

Comment: If it's three scoops per container but only two flavours, then apparently there will be two scoops of one flavour and one of the other. Therefore, the linking table should probably have at least one more column to specify the number of scoops of that specific flavour in that specific container.

Comment: I am beginning to think there is no solution.  What I am trying to model is 10 flavors. For containers there are 5, small cone can take only one scoop, large cone gets two scoops, small cup gets one scoop, medium cup gets 2 scoops and large cup gets three scoops.  The scoops can be all one flavor or any combination of the 10 flavors.  Then for the toppings I was hoping to do the same but for cones only one topping and for cups any combination of 3 toppings, where there are 7 toppings.  Each topping flavor and container all with its own associated price.  Toppings being optional of course.

Comment: @WilliamS There's definitely a solution, and it's actually a pretty standard problem you're trying to model. Apologies, I wrote my solution above up in haste on my phone, so I have to review your requirements more closely and will update my answer accordingly (hopefully today if I get a minute). Don't feel astray, there is definitely a simple way! :)

Comment: i guess I should also note that one of my toppings is 'None' with a price of 0 which takes care of the optional topping issue.  I appreciate you looking at this for me.

Comment: @WilliamS Please see my updated answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
-- Customer CST exists.
--
customer {CST}
      PK {CST}
```

- *Fare* is a generic term (food, drink) for anything you sell. *Fare* is the supertype for *container*, *flavor*, and *topping*.

```
-- Fare FRE, of fare-type TYP, named NME,
-- is currently priced at PRI dollars per unit.
--
fare {FRE, TYP, NME, PRI}
  PK {FRE}
  AK {NME}
  SK {FRE, TYP}

CHECK TYP in (C, F, T)
```

```
-- Container FRE (a fare of type TYP = 'C') ...
--
container_ {FRE, TYP, container_specific}
        PK {FRE}

CHECK TYP = 'C'

FK {FRE, TYP} REFERENCES fare {FRE, TYP}
```

```
-- Ice cream flavor FRE (a fare of type TYP = 'F') ...
--
flavor {FRE, TYP, flavor_specific}
    PK {FRE}

CHECK TYP = 'F'

FK {FRE, TYP} REFERENCES fare {FRE, TYP}
```

```
-- Topping (a fare of type TYP = 'T') ...
--
topping {FRE, TYP, topping_specific}
     PK {FRE}

CHECK TYP = 'T'

FK {FRE, TYP} REFERENCES fare {FRE, TYP}
```

```
-- Customer CST placed an order ORDR.
--
order_ {ORDR, CST}
    PK {ORDR}

FK {CST} REFERENCES customer {CST}
```

```
-- Item number ITM_NO of order ORDR exists.
--
line_item {ORDR, ITM_NO}
       PK {ORDR, ITM_NO}

FK {ORDR} REFERENCES order_ {ORDR}
```

Capture the current sale price `PRI` into `PRI_TS`. This way you can change prices and not affect previous orders.

```
-- Item number ITM_NO of order ORDR includes
-- fare FRE, of fare-type TYP, in quantity of QTY;
-- priced at PRI_TS dollars per unit at the time of sale.
--
item_detail {ORDR, ITM_NO, FRE, TYP, QTY, PRI_TS}
         PK {ORDR, ITM_NO, FRE}

      FK1 {ORDR, ITM_NO} REFERENCES
line_item {ORDR, ITM_NO}

 FK2 {FRE, TYP} REFERENCES
fare {FRE, TYP}

-- Each order item is served in at most one container.
--
CHECK (   (TYP  = 'C' and QTY =  1) 
       OR (TYP != 'C' and QTY >= 1)
      )
```

---

Notes:

```
All attributes (columns) NOT NULL

PK = Primary Key
AK = Alternate Key   (Unique)
SK = Proper Superkey (Unique)
FK = Foreign Key
```

A word about *subtypes*. The proper way to implement constraints for subtypes would be to use assertions (`CREATE ASSERTION`), but it is still not available in major DBs. I am using `FKs` instead, and as all other substitute methods it is not perfect. People argue a lot, on SO and SE-DBA, what is better. I would encourage you to check other methods too.